# Libreoffice crashing after splash screen

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice

I attempted to open an ODT and ODS file with LibreOffice on a fresh copy of Lubuntu 18.10. The splash screen came up and when it finished loading, it crashed.

Below is some terminal output, where I tried running in safe mode:

```
craptasticlaptop@craptasticlaptop:~$ libreoffice --safe-mode

(soffice:12460): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:14:33.493: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(soffice:12460): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:14:33.618: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Papirus-Dark/16x16/actions/image-missing.svg: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Application Error
craptasticlaptop@craptasticlaptop:~$
```

If I'm reading this right, it's crashing because of an icon? That seems rather unusual. If that is the case, how should I fix it? An unrecognized file format sounds like I need to just install something, but if so, what?

Of course, I could be completely wrong, and the issue is something else.

EDIT: I've tried this with the latest version of LibreOffice that came with the default repositories, as well as the LibreOffice PPA. Both have the same issue. Also attempted to purge and reinstall all LibreOffice related packages, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

```
locate action-unavailable.svg
```

and create a symlink to

```
/usr/share/icons/Papirus-Dark/16x16/actions/image-missing.svg
```

[The project page](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme/blob/master/Papirus-Dark/16x16/actions/image-missing.svg) has it listed as a symlink.

> EDIT: I've tried this with the latest version of LibreOffice that came with the default repositories, as well as the LibreOffice PPA. Both have the same issue. Also attempted to purge and reinstall all LibreOffice related packages, to no avail.

Problem is the icon pack. Not libreoffice.

Comment: Running `sudo ln -s /path/image-missing.svg /path/action/unavailable.svg` gives me a `file exists` error. Tried it with the paths the other way around as well.